# Post statement not returning a value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a javascript fucntion below

```
function loginsubmit() {
    var url = "../php/loginsubmit.php";
    var data = "";
    ajaxRequest(url, "POST",data , true, insertNewBody);
}
```

Which then creates my ajax request to post to my php code which is

```
<?php
   session_start();

   require_once ("db.php");

   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password' ];
    echo $username;

    $query = "select * from logindetails where username='$username' and  password='$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
    } else {
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = FALSE;
    }
    mysql_close();
?>
```

These two pieces of code below are returning a null value and i can't see why?

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Comment: What's `ajaxRequest`? Are you using a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clarified by others already, you are not sending data.. here is how you should:

```
function loginsubmit() {
    var url = "../php/loginsubmit.php";
    var username = document.myLoginForm.username.value;
    var password = document.myLoginForm.password.value;
    ajaxRequest(url, "POST", {username: username, password: password}, true, insertNewBody);
}
```

replace "myLoginForm" with the actual name of your form. Also there are other ways too to retrive values from input fields such as using element IDs of those feilds.

Comment: "As clarified by others already, you" don't need to repeat others.

Comment: others haven't added how to retrieve value for an input... I guess its no sin to add a little more details

Comment: Well, that information is obtainable with a simple Googling… and isn't really relevant to the question… kinda useless.

Comment: that guy is probably here because of simple "Googling"... Anyway I have nothing to argue and I see no harm done with my answer except it becomes more clear to OP

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're actually never setting the post values `username` and `password` in your javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Put data in your `data` variable:

```
function loginsubmit() {
    var url = "../php/loginsubmit.php";
    var data = {username: 'yourusername', password: 'yourpassword'};
    ajaxRequest(url, "POST",data , true, insertNewBody);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An ajax suggestion based on what Ruben is saying, you need to pass the username and password up to PHP in your login call.

```
$.ajax({
url : "../php/loginsubmit.php",
type: "POST",
data : {username:"theUsernameString",password:"thePasswordString"},
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    //data - contains the response from server
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
{
   //handle the error
}
});
```